# Adding each number in the range from min_value to max_value together. Then return total

Tags: python

```
def sum_series(min_value, max_value):
      min_max_list = []
   for i in range(min_value, max_value):
      min_max_list.append(i + 1)
   return sum(min_max_list)
print(sum_series(1, 3))
```

I suppose to get total of 6, I don't know what I'm wrong here. Can you help?
assert sum_series(1, 3) == 6  # 1 + 2 + 3

Comment: It's not indented properly. Is that the problem you're asking about?

Comment: By the way, it's possible to calculate this in constant time, if you're interested.

Comment: what's wrong with `sum(range(min_value, max_value+1))` ?

Comment: it works in the VScode but doesn't work in the program I am submitting because I need to use def function and for loop.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this?

```
min_value = 1
max_value = 3
print(sum(range(min_value, max_value + 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_series(min_value, max_value):
    min_max_list = []
    for i in range(min_value, max_value):
        min_max_list.append(i + 1)
    return sum(min_max_list)


print(sum_series(1, 3))
```

In Python, the range function, in `for x in range(start, end)` the start value is what `x` actually starts to be, but at the end of the loop, where you expect `x` to be `end`, it's actually `end - 1` that's `end` minus `1`. Also, your code wasn't indented properly. The above code is the fixed version, and outputs 5. If you wanted to output 6, then you would do `sum_series(0, 3)` , where x is 0, and ends to be 2. In your code you append to the list `x+1` so when `x` is 0, `1` is appended, then `2`, then `3` where `x` was `2`. (That's for when you have 0 and 3 as the parameters) With 1 and 3 as the parameters, in your code, the list is actually: `[2, 3]`.

Edit:
If you wanted to keep the parameters but still output 6, then I guess you could:

```
def sum_series(min_value, max_value):
    min_max_list = []
    min_max_list.append(min_value)  # Append the min_value first
    for i in range(min_value, max_value):
        min_max_list.append(i + 1)
    return sum(min_max_list)


print(sum_series(1, 3))
```

Comment: This is assert given and I have to use for loop                                                 Assert sum_series(1, 3) == 6  # 1 + 2 + 3